# When does the derivative of the logarithm equal the logarithm of the derivative?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Not sure how to show proof of work, but I have several pages of notes on my bathroom floor right now. All I get is horribly complicated nonlinear DEs. Is there a magic substitution that makes differentiation and logarithm commute?

What I'm asking for is solutions to:

$$\dfrac d {dx} \ln( f(x) ) = \ln\left( \dfrac d {dx} f(x) \right )$$

Comment: It probably doesn't have a nice solution. Mathematica gives something in terms of an inverse function of something involving the [Lambert $W$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Comment: Thanks! I don't have access to Mathematica, so that's a huge help. Sorry for bothering you guys

Comment: You can differentiate one more time to get rid of log and obtain non-linear ODE

Comment: @Vasili You don't need another differentiation to get there, just a substitution. And yes, that one is currently sitting on my bathroom floor. :/

Comment: The Lambert W does make sense to me. I already tried substitutions like g(x) = f(x) ln( f(x) ) and the like

Comment: Thanks for the edit @bjcolby15

Comment: I think substitution $g(x)=f(x) e^{f(x)}$ makes more sense if Lambert W is present.

Comment: @Vasili But it's the inverse, remember

Comment: For the record, I did ask Chat GPT and it gave me an answer with 0 information. https://i.imgur.com/xe4UD7u.png

Comment: Again, thanks for the edit! Not sure how to "at" editors, the obvious method was a hard fail the last time. But you know who you are, you absolute legends! :)

Comment: @EmanuelLandeholm  lol you're welcome.

Comment: If you write it as $y'/y=\ln(y')$, it seems plausible that the $W$ function will be involved if you want to solve for $y'$ (since $y'$ occurs both "free" and "inside the logarithm"). Once you get the ODE on the form $y'=g(y)$, it can be solved (in principle) using separation of variables: $\int \frac{dy}{g(y)} = \int dx$, etc.

Comment: ChatGPT is worse than useless for exact science. It is good enough to produce something that looks coherent, but the actual contents is just idiotic rambling.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I think we´re fast approaching the point where Chat GPT outperforms Google Search. Still a long ways to go...

Comment: Yes, and in 20 years we will have unlimited fusion power, seriously. What is the metric for "outperform"? The internet is a heap of garbage, most of which you will never see, but a search engine will have this as input. AI promises to, at least, extract some kind of topical information. But it can not reason about it, the current state-of-the-art is word associations (ok, with sentence structure, association of phrases), it is not comprehension and "common-sense checks". So in the end it remains GIGO.

Comment: I set the bar pretty low. Google Search has deteriorated in quality the last decade. I mean really deteriorated. And I'd argue that it's not just a case of GIGO. There are big economic incentives for polluting search results. Just my tin foil take.

ChatGPT is not swallowing the web like wholesale. There are filters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Introducing the parameter $\tau=f'_x$,
\begin{align}
f=\frac{\tau}{\log(\tau)}\quad\rightarrow\quad \mathrm df=\frac{\mathrm d\tau}{\log(\tau)}-\frac{\mathrm d\tau}{log(\tau)^2}
\end{align}

substituting for $\mathrm df$ we have
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm d\tau}=\frac{1}{\tau\log(\tau)}-\frac{1}{\tau\log(\tau)^2}.
\end{align}
upon integration we find a nice parametric solution
\begin{align}
f(\tau)=\frac{\tau}{\log(\tau)},\quad x(\tau)=\log(\log(\tau))+\frac{1}{\log(\tau)}+C.
\end{align}

Comment: I'm going to be accepting this answer partially on faith, because I haven't yet found the time to do my homework.  I guess I wish stackexchange would allow you to outsource accepts. Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your condition is equivalent to the ODE
$$\frac{y'}{y}=\ln(y')\Rightarrow -\frac{1}{y}=\frac{1}{y'}\ln(\frac{1}{y'})$$
knowing that the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) obeys
$$W(ae^a)=a\Rightarrow W(\ln(a)e^{\ln(a)})=\ln(a)\Rightarrow W(a\ln(a))=\ln(a) $$
we have
$$W(-\frac{1}{y})=W(\frac{1}{y'}\ln(\frac{1}{y'}))=\ln(\frac{1}{y'})\Rightarrow$$
$$\frac{1}{y'}=\exp(W(-\frac{1}{y}))$$
separating variables we get
$$\int dt=\int \exp(W(-\frac{1}{y}))dy.$$
Note also that $W(x)e^{W(x)}=x$ implies $e^{W(x)}=\frac{x}{W(x)}$, so
$$\int \exp(W(-\frac{1}{y}))dy=\int -\frac{1}{yW(-\frac{1}{y})}dy$$
substituting $W(-\frac{1}{y})=u \Rightarrow -\frac{1}{y}=ue^u \Rightarrow \frac{1}{y^2}dy=(1+u)e^udu$ we get
$$\int -\frac{1}{yW(-\frac{1}{y})}dy=\int -\frac{y}{y^2W(-\frac{1}{y})}dy = 
\int \frac{1}{u^2e^u}(1+u)e^udu$$
$$\int \frac{1}{u^2}(1+u)du= \ln(u)-\frac{1}{u}=\ln(|W(-\frac{1}{y})|)-\frac{1}{W(-\frac{1}{y})} $$
so the solution becomes
$$t+C = \ln(|W(-\frac{1}{y})|)-\frac{1}{W(-\frac{1}{y})} $$

Comment: Just before “substituting”, $W(1/y)$ should be $W(-1/y)$, and this affects the rest of the computation.

Comment: I think you ought to get $x+C = \ln|W(-1/y)|-1/W(-1/y)$. (Plotting this, it seems to agree with what Eli Bartlett's answer gives for $1 < \tau < e$. That answer also produces another branch for $\tau > e$.)

Comment: Thank you both for your valuable feedback!

Comment: @HansLundmark you're right, already edited.

Comment: After the edit, I kind of want to accept this answer too!

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a late answer, but I thought it would be nice to see some graphs!

The ODE is
$$
(\ln(y))' = \ln(y')
,
$$
so if we want to stay within the world of real numbers, we need both $y$ and $y'$ to be positive.
We can rewrite the equation as
$$
\frac{y'}{y} = \ln(y')
\iff
y = \frac{y'}{\ln(y')}
.
$$
Consider the function $g(s) = \frac{s}{\ln(s)}$, $s>0$.
The figure below shows its graph, which can be found using simple calculus; it decreases for $1<s<e$ down to the local minimum $g(e)=e$, and then it increases to $\infty$.

[image]

This means that the equation $y = g(y') = \frac{y'}{\ln(y')}$ has two positive solutions for $y'$ for each given value of $y \in (e,\infty)$; one solution in the interval $y' \in (1,e)$
and the other one in the interval $y' \in (e,\infty)$.
These two choices give rise to two corresponding ODEs $y'=h_1(y)$ and $y'=h_2(y)$, whose solutions $y(x)$ are both solutions to the original ODE.
One of these solutions has a relatively gentle slope (always between $1$ and $e$) and the other one has a steeper slope
(always greater than $e$), and both lie in the region $y(x)>e$:

[image]

Since the ODE is autonomous, any translate of these curves in the $x$ direction is of course also a solution;
this corresponds to different choices of the constant $C$ in the formulas below.
The plot shows the case $C=0$.
The maximal open interval of existence in this case is $x \in (1,\infty)$,
although the two functions $y(x)$ both extend continuously to the interval $x \in [1,\infty)$ with $y(1)=e$ and with the one-sided derivative $y'_+(1)=e$.

The parametric solution formula found by Eli Barlett,
$$
\bigl( x(t), y(t) \bigr) = \left( \ln(\ln(t)) + \frac{1}{\ln t} + C, \frac{t}{\ln t} \right)
,
$$
produces the red curve for $1 < t \le e$
and the blue curve for $t \ge e$.
(Recall that the parameter $t$ was nothing but the slope $y' = \tfrac{dy}{dx} = \tfrac{dy/dt}{dx/dt}$ at the point $(x(t),y(t))$.)

And the implicit solution formula (giving the inverse function $x=x(y)$)
found by Diego Santos,
$$
x =
\ln\bigl| W \bigl( -\tfrac{1}{y} \bigr) \bigr| - \frac{1}{W \bigl( -\tfrac{1}{y} \bigr)}
+ C
,\qquad
y \ge e
,
$$
gives the red curve when $W = W_0$ is the principal branch of the Lambert W-function,
which is increasing and maps the interval $[-1/e,0)$ to the interval $[-1,0)$,
and gives the blue curve when $W = W_{-1}$ is the other real-valued branch,
which is decreasing and maps the interval $[-1/e,0)$ to the interval $(-\infty,-1]$.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Very illuminating +1